# Enable pointer-events when click on an iframe embedded map

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, iframe

I have a map in an iframe tag and works pretty fine. All that I want is when click on frame the pointer-events enable again and interact (zoom, click on markers etc)

```
<iframe id="map" src="map.html"></iframe>
```

In my css file I have the following style

```
#map {
        margin-left:0px;
        width:107%;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

The pointer events works and I can't interact with the map. 
The thing I want is when click on map the pointer-events becomes 'auto'

I have tried this code of javascript and nothing happens. Any ideas?

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#map').css('pointer-events', 'none');

      $('#map').click(function() {
        $(this).css('pointer-events', 'auto');
      });
   });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

you cannot get click event of an element which have "pointer-event:none". what you should do is just add that  inside a div.

for example,

```
<div class="map-wrapper"><iframe id="map"></iframe></div>
```

then, call your script as

```
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#map').css('pointer-events', 'none');
          $('.map-wrapper').click(function() {
            $(this).find('#map').css('pointer-events', 'auto'); // just $('#map') also fine
          });
          $('.map-wrapper').mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).find('#map').css('pointer-events', 'none'); // making it not clickable when it's not in focus
          });

       });
    </script>
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful! In the end I changed the `.click` event to a `.mouseenter` event, then stored a variable of if I was interacting with another element outside the iframe based on that element's `onmousedown` event. In the `.mouseenter` function, I then said if there is not an interaction outside the iframe, then execute. This lets you drag within the iframe without having to click first.

Comment: Wow, now that I think about it I could have just used `.onmousedown`. Silly me! Too late now, it's pointless to change it.